# Simplify fractions and square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I would like to 'Simplify'

```
Sqrt[5/6]/2
```

to

```
Sqrt[5/24]
```

I've tried to penalize Times and Rational using ComplexityFunction, but something like

```
mysim[e_] := 
 100 (Count[e, _Times, {0, Infinity}] + 
     Count[e, _Rational, {0, Infinity}]) + LeafCount[e]
```

did not do work.

Suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Mathematica brings some simple expressions to a canonical form.  For example, `2/4` (i.e. `Rational[2,4]`) is immediately and automatically transformed to `1/2`. `Divide[a, b]` is immediately transformed to `Times[a,Power[b,-1]]`.  `b+a` becomes `a+b`.  Such canonicalization aids equality testing.  Similarly, `Sqrt[5/24]` immediately evaluates to `Sqrt[5/6]/2`.  Thus `Simplify` can never return the former.

Comment: Ref: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ReducingExpressionsToTheirStandardForm.html  To maintain `Sqrt[5/24]` in its given form, `Hold` or `HoldForm` must be applied.  I'm not commenting on whether that can be done with Simplify conveniently or whether it is worth doing, but it's likely not very simple to do.

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs, that put me on the way to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following function works (under the side condition that everything is real...

```
ToSingleFractionForm[a_] := Block[{b}, b = a^2; Sign[a] Sqrt[TraditionalForm[b]]]
```

The TraditionalForm wrapper is enough to stop Mathematica from putting things in canonical form. And TeXForm on it still works.