# How not to Simplify square roots

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Given

```
t1 = {1/7 (4 + Sqrt[37]), 1/15 (3 + 2 Sqrt[7]), 1/2 (5 + 3 Sqrt[2])}
```

I do not want to simplify the square roots. I want to get

```
t2 = {1/7 (4 + Sqrt[37]), 1/15 (3 + Sqrt[28]), 1/2 (5 + Sqrt[18])}
```

I can cheat my way round by code:

```
t2 = t1[[All, 2, -1]]
t3 = t2^2
Defer[Sqrt[#]] & /@ t3
```

to get

```
{Sqrt[37], Sqrt[28], Sqrt[18]}
```

and fiddle it in again. What is an elegant way to obtain t2? How could I use `Cases` inserting two optional patterns? I tried with `If` inside `Cases` but that didn't do the job properly.

Comment: The problem is that Mathematica automatically likes to write `Sqrt[28]` as `2 Sqrt[7]`. So you will fighting against the front end all the time trying to prevent it from doing this. But   why exactly you want it displayed `Sqrt[28]` vs `2 Sqrt[7]`? Is it just for display purposes? computationally there is no difference.

Comment: I kinda remember now this was asked before on this forum...may be if you search you might find it.

Comment: The roots show up in a sequence i am interested in. I found similar questions about this problem but structures where a bit easier.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101618/simplify-fractions-and-square-roots

Comment: I am reliably certain that it is not the Mathematica front end that converts Sqrt[28] to 2*Sqrt[7].

Answer (score 2):

maybe replace Sqrt first?

```
{1/7 (4 + Sqrt[37]), 1/15 (3 + 2 Sqrt[7]), 1/2 (5 + 3 Sqrt[2])} //
#/. Sqrt[x_] :> f[x]& //
#/. a_ f[b_] :> f[a^2 b]& //
#/. f[x_] :> Defer[Sqrt[x]] &
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this helpful? It may be too fragile for your use-case but the desired output is obtained.

```
expr=Inactivate[{1/7 (4 + Sqrt[37]), 1/15 (3 + 2 Sqrt[7]), 1/2 (5 + 3 Sqrt[2])}, Sqrt] 

expr//.Times[a_, Inactive[Sqrt][b_]] -> Inactive[Sqrt][a^2*b]
```

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is, that I already get t1 in the simplified square root form with the square root sign (which I cannot copy here because it comes out as Sqrt).

Comment: Oh, I think I understand you. When I define `t1` and then try to inactivate stuff in it in later lines the method does not work. I did some looking in the documentation and it suggests that there is a variable `$InactivateExclusions` whose value determines that Inactivate should ignore certain heads. Probably those heads include stuff that is displayed in special ways by the front end like $$\sqrt{}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a reasonable solution:

```
t1 = {1/7 (4 + Sqrt[37]), 1/15 (3 + 2 Sqrt[7]), 1/2 (5 + 3 Sqrt[2])};
Replace[#, a_*(b_ + c_*Sqrt[d_]) :> a*(b + Hold[Sqrt[c^2*d]])] & /@ t1;
% /. Hold[e_] :> Defer[e]
```

Which gives

```
{1/7 (4 + Sqrt[37]), 1/15 (3 + Sqrt[2^2 7]), 1/2 (5 + Sqrt[3^2 2])}
```

How would I evaluate just the number under the root and keep the rest?

Comment: replace Sqrt with f, eval the num, replace f[num] with defer[sqrt[num]]

Comment: Thanks, I think that this is equivalent to my "cheating" method